# forEach function does not await to return buffer on AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, async-await

I have written the following function on lambda for reading images from s3 bucket and compressing it with different renditions. Renditions are stored as an environment variable in a lambda function. I read those renditions and convert it into an array then iterate through it. While iterating I'm trying to compress an image using sharpjs library with current rendition element which is nothing but a JSON object. forEach starts at line no 21 but though it is awaiting, it does not await for code below line 42 to get executed and continue the iteration from there. So I get console.log("before destination bucket"); executed thrice but not the actual logic. When I use the same code for a single element it's working fine.

Could anyone please help me out here?

```
  1 const aws = require('aws-sdk');
2     const s3 = new aws.S3();
3     const sharp = require('sharp');
4     const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
5     exports.handler = async (event) => {
6         let renditions = process.env.renditions;
7         const bucketName = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
8         const fileName = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
9         console.log(event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name);
10        console.log(event.Records[0].s3.object.key);
11        try {
12            let uuid = uuidv4();
13            const file = await s3
14                .getObject({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: fileName })
15                .promise();
16            console.log(file.Body);
17            const putAsItIs = await s3.putObject({ Bucket: "dev-originals", Key: uuidv4() + "/" + fileName, Body: file.Body }).promise();
18            console.log("putAsItIs" + putAsItIs.Body);
19            const deleted = await s3.deleteObject({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: fileName }).promise();
20            let renditionsArray = JSON.parse(renditions);
21            await  renditionsArray.forEach(async (rendition) => {
22            try {
23                console.log("forEach start");
24
25                try {
26                    console.log("rendition" + rendition);
27                    let path = uuid;
28                    if (rendition.name == "WebCompress") {
29                        path = path + "/WC";
30                    }
31                    if (rendition.name == "Thumbnail") {
32                        path = path + "/TN";
33                    }
34                    if (rendition.name == "WebPreview") {
35                        path = path + "/WP";
36                    }
37
38                    console.log("Before buffer" + rendition.width + rendition.quality);
39                    console.log("before distination bucket");
40                    // Upload the thumbnail image to the destination bucket
41
42                    let space = "srgb";
43                    var buffer = await sharp(file.Body).resize(rendition.width).withMetadata().toColorspace(space).webp({ quality: rendition.quality }).toBuffer();
44                    console.log("buffer" + buffer);
45                    try {
46                        const destparams = {
47                            Bucket: "dev-webcompressed",
48                            Key: path + "/" + fileName,
49                            Body: buffer,
50                            ContentType: "image"
51                        };
52                        const putResult = await s3.putObject(destparams).promise();
53                        console.log("putResult : " + putResult)
54                    } catch (error) {
55                        console.log(error);
56                        return;
57                    }
58                } catch (error) {
59                    console.log("Inner" + error);
60                }
61            }
62            catch (error) {
63                console.log("Inner" + error);
64            }
65
66            });
67        } catch (err) {
68            console.log("Outer" + err);
69        }
70
71        // TODO implement
72        const response = {
73            statusCode: 200,
74            body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
75        };
76        return response;
77    };
```

Comment: Switch to a `for ... of` loop. Or write an async-capable forEach variant (example: https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404).

Comment: tried with for..of loop already still issue persist..